# (goto-char (region-end)) doesn't set the point to the end of the region

Tags: region, comment, insert

I have written a small elisp script which should  put oneline or multiline comments based on the current buffer's major mode. The source file is here: https://github.com/amirteymuri/Com/blob/master/com.el

The `insert-comm+` function which should insert the multiline comments however puts the ending multline-comment string not at the end of the marked region, but some characters before it (depending on major-mode the amount of characters change also). Can someone see where the problem is happening?
This is the `insert-comm+` definition:

```
(defun insert-comm+ ()
  "Inserts multiliners to a marked region or a line."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((comm-list (comm+))
     (comm-begin (concat (first comm-list) "\n"))
     (comm-end (concat "\n" (second comm-list))))
    (if (use-region-p)
      (let ((b (region-beginning))
            (e (region-end)))
       (progn
        (goto-char b)
        (insert comm-begin)
        (goto-char (1+ e))
        (insert comm-end)))
      (progn
       (insert comm-begin)
       (insert comm-end)
       (backward-char (length comm-end))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `e` to the value of `(region-end)`, which is the position of the end of the region at the time you call the function. Then you insert `comm-begin` somewhere before `e`. So `e` is no longer at the end of the region, but *n* characters before where *n* is the length of `comm-begin`. I guess you tried to compensate by using `(1+ e`) instead of `e`, but that only gives the right result if `comm-begin` is a single character.

The proper fix is simple: retrieve the region boundaries only when you need them.

You should also decide whether you want to end up with the comment delimiters inside or outside the region and use [`insert-before-markers`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Insertion.html#index-insert_002dbefore_002dmarkers-3552) accordingly. Use it to insert the beginning delimiter to keep the delimiters outside the region, or to insert the end delimiter to keep the delimiters inside.

```el
(if (use-region-p)
    (progn
      (goto-char (region-beginning))
      (insert-before-markers comm-begin)
      (goto-char (region-end))
      (insert comm-end))
  (insert comm-begin)
  (insert-before-markers comm-end))
```

Also, you should wrap this function in [`save-excursion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/save_002dexcursion.html) so that it leaves the point in place instead of moving it to the end.

Overall, I don't understand what you're trying to do. Emacs already knows how to begin and end a comment in all major modes: the information is in the variables [`comment-start` and `comment-end`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Options-for-Comments.html). And Emacs already has [commands to comment out a region](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comments.html#Comments).